# An example of an open discontinuous function

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

Consider the following simple example of a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is open and discontinuous at all points. If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is represented as *something*.$x_1x_2x_3\dots$ in the binary system, then set $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}$$ if the limit exists and belongs to $(0,1)$, and set $f(x)$ to (say) $\frac{1}{2}$ otherwise.

Is this example known (I suppose it is), and what's the reference for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw it as an exercise (E1.4.2) in the book "Analysis Now" by "Gert. K. Pedersen" with slight difference; $f$ is defined by 
$$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R,\quad x\mapsto\limsup\frac1n{\sum_{k=1}^nx_n}$$
where $x-\lfloor x\rfloor=0.x_1x_2\dots$ is the binary expansion of the 
fractional part of $x$.

Comment: $f$ should be valued in $[0,1]$ if you want it to be open. To have it open while valued in $\mathbf{R}$, change the values $0$, $1$ to $1/2$.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is often called the [Cesàro-Vietoris function](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Ces%C3%A0ro-Vietoris+function%22) (see my various comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996246/examples-of-dense-sets-in-the-complex-plane/996872#996872) also).

Comment: @YCor Of course to get an open map,  it is hinted in the mentioned exercise to consider $h\circ f$, where $h$ is any surjective continuous functions from $[0,1]$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, see your "***here***" for the Wacław Sierpiński's example.

Answer (score 5):

The following open question was popular in some places:

**Q:**   does there exist $\ x\in(0;1)\ $ such that $\,\ s(x)=x,\,\ $ where

$$ s(x)\ :=\ \lim_{n=\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}n $$

and $\ x_n\ $ are binary digits $\ 0\ $ or $\ 1,\ $ and

$$ x\ =\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{2^n} $$

Thus, in 1959/60 I've formulated and proved a more general theorem, and it was recognized in the spring of 1961, namely:

**Theorem**   For  every function $\ f: (0;1)\rightarrow (0;1)\ $ which is a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions, and for every non-empty $\  (a;b)\subseteq (0;1),\ $ the equation

$$ s(x)\ =\ f(x) $$

has $\ 2^{\aleph_0} $ of different solutions $\ x\in (a;b).$

> **Remark**   there is something of a paradox due to the juxtaposition of the equation $\ s(x)=f(x)\ $ and the classical Jacques Hadamard equation $\ s(x)=\frac 12,\ $ which holds for almost all $\ x\in[0;1].$